# optimize/improve client side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items that I need to record its position in the list - i.e. sort order, I am running the code below to bind on the stop event - however with 180 fields, this is quite slow on my machine, can this be optimized?

```
$(".survey-fields").bind("sortstop", function(event, ui) {
        $(".report-field").each(function(i) {
            $(".sorted-fields").find("#" + $(this).data("field-id")).val(i + 1);
        });
    });
```

Code explanation:
I have a list of sortable divs, each div has an id (db unique id, a number), then I have another list that is hidden, I copy over the new position into the relevant field

Before I was using field names as a string and not ids as I am using now, not sure if that is making it very slow. I have jquery ui 1.8.16

```
<div data-field-id="41" class="display-wrapper report-field">
    <div class="field-header field-move">
        <span>name: fieldname</span> | <span>max length:
                100</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s field-icon field-toggle" title="show/hide details of this field"></span>
    </div>
 <div> whatever here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Any other workarounds that I could do... basically I need to send a list of ids and their sortorder to my `controller` via `ajax` request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without proper profiling. This

```
  $(".sorted-fields").find("#" + $(this).data("field-id"))
```

can be simplified to just

```
  $("#" + $(this).data("field-id"))
```

because id are (should be) unique document-wide. Another thought: if you're using ajax anyways, what's the point of populating form fields? Why not use a simple object, which can be sent to the server in json. Like

```
    var sortOrder = {}

    $(".report-field").each(function(i) {
        sortOrder[$(this).data("field-id")] = i + 1;
    });
```

Comment: if I want to send the field id alongside its position, how would I populate the json?